# Elasticsearch search result in string field is not in correct order or relevance

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.7.4 version.

I'm trying to search `Title` keyword in `title` field as you can see below.

**ES**

```
curl -XGET "http://127.0.0.1:9203/_search?post_dev" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "Title"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": "0",
  "size": "10"
}'
```

Result is in here: http://pastebin.com/tkd3KKN7

I indexed table below and just showing you a particular search result. Based on what we see below, at least the row **13** or **16** or **17** or **19** should have appeared on top of ES query result above unless I'm missing something. Adding `"sort":[{"_score":"desc"}]` doesn't change anything. Is there something wrong with my indexing or the query?

**MySQL**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM post WHERE title LIKE '%Title%' LIMIT 10;
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | title   | description | author        | year | price | is_published | created_at          |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
|  2 | Title 1 | Desc 1      | Pacino        | 2015 |  2.50 |            1 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
|  3 | Title 1 | Cript A     | DeNiro        | 2010 |  1.00 |            0 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
|  9 | Title 3 | Desc 2      | Al            | 2010 |  0.50 |            1 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
| 10 | Title 1 | Cript A     | Andy Garcia   | 2015 |  0.50 |            1 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
| 12 | Title 2 | Desc 1      | Andy Garcia   | 2015 |  4.00 |            1 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
| 13 | Title   | Cript       | Robert        | 2010 |  3.99 |            0 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
| 16 | Title   | Title       | Andy Garcia   | 2005 |  1.00 |            1 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
| 17 | Title 2 | Title       | Robert DeNiro | 2005 |  4.00 |            0 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
| 19 | Title   | Cript B     | DeNiro        | 2010 |  3.99 |            1 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
| 24 | Title   | Cript B     | Robert DeNiro | 2000 |  2.50 |            1 | 2016-03-11 23:36:33 |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------+------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Index**

```
$ curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:9203/post_dev?pretty
{
  "post_dev" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "post" : {
        "_meta" : {
          "model" : "Application\\SearchBundle\\Entity\\Post"
        },
        "properties" : {
          "created_at" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "description" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : "english",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "is_published" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "price" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : "english",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "year" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1457739680793",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1070499"
        },
        "uuid" : "mxQFFQ0EROuCDZvUjIj0-w"
      }
    },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, there are 2206 matches and they all have the same score (`1.8570213`), so in that case they simply come back in the same order as they are in their respective Lucene segment (until a segment merge happens upon indexing, updating, deleting, etc).

Your SQL table is naturally sorted by `id`. So if you change your query to also sort by id, you'll see the docs 13, 16, 19 and 24 first, like in your SQL table:

```
curl -XGET "http://127.0.0.1:9203/_search?post_dev" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "Title"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": "0",
  "size": "10".
  "sort": {"id": "asc"}
}'
```

Comment: Looks like ES and MySQL score records differently so that's way full-text result-set differ which is what confused me in first place. Thanks.